# Encryption Decryption in windows phone8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt my data using the AES algorith.I got the functions from the MSDN site [encryption decryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx). What i am doing is i'm encrypting the data and storing it as a string using the following method
`byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(response, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
  string saveresponse = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);`

and then i save it in IsolatedStorageSettings

```
settings.Add(merchantId, saveresponse);
```

But the problem i am facing is when the user comes after sometime and hits my page i check first in the IsolatedStorageSettings object if the data is present i pass that data to decrypt and process further.The step i use to decrypt is as follows

```
byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String(response);


response = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(temp, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
```

But the above line gives me error **"Value can not be null.
Parameter name: inputBuffer"**

I am unable to find where i am going wrong.Can u guys please let me know what steps should be taken to make it up and running.

Here is the Encryption Code

```
 static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments. 
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an AesManaged object 
        // with the specified key and IV. 
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption. 
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


  return encrypted;
}
```

and here is the decryption code

```
    static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        try
        {
            // Check arguments. 
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

            // Declare the string used to hold 
            // the decrypted text. 
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an AesManaged object 
            // with the specified key and IV. 
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption. 
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return plaintext;

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Error";
        }
    }
```

and on button1 click i call the encryption method

```
using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
                                    {

byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(response, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
string saveresponse = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}
```

and on button 2 i call decryption method

```
using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
                                        {

    byte[] temp= Convert.FromBase64String(response)
    response = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(temp, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
    }
```

Comment: Show more code. Like `DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes`.

Comment: @weston i have made changes to the question, please check

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();                                                           in the  DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes() method....is this issue related to myAes.Key and myAes.IV as i am new to encryption i am not getting what is going on.

Comment: Maybe this question answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12647794/360211

Comment: @weston How can i set myAes.Key and myAes.IV values same for both encryption and decryption.Can i set it at global level.If yes can u please guide through

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged()){}` block what it does it generates the new key and IV for encryption and decryption.So while decryption the key and IV doesnt match hence the error generates.Just remove the using block and declare the Aesmanaged myAes object at global level and the problem is solved. So the final code would look like

```
AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged();
```

On button one click to encrypt;

byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(response, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
string saveresponse = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

and button2 click to decrypt

```
byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String(response);


response = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(temp, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
```

Thats it, happpy coding.